Are non-citizens in the USA "sojourners"?
The Bible contains a number of verses about how sojourners should be treated. "Sojourner" means "temporary resident", and the Bible seems to use the word mean anybody who is living in a foreign country, however long they may be staying or whatever they may be doing.
In the USA there are some 40 million resident aliens, of which around 11 million are "undocumented" (meaning they have no legal permission to be in the USA).
Are all these people "sojourners" in the Biblical meaning of the word? I'm particularly interested in the verses about how sojourners are to be treated. In particular:

Leviticus 24:22 You shall have the same rule for the sojourner and for the native, for I am the Lord your God.

Deuteronomy 24:19-21 “When you reap your harvest in your field and forget a sheaf in the field, you shall not go back to get it. It shall be for the sojourner, the fatherless, and the widow, that the Lord your God may bless you in all the work of your hands. When you beat your olive trees, you shall not go over them again. It shall be for the sojourner, the fatherless, and the widow. When you gather the grapes of your vineyard, you shall not strip it afterward. It shall be for the sojourner, the fatherless, and the widow.

Deuteronomy 27:19 ‘Cursed be anyone who perverts the justice due to the sojourner, the fatherless, and the widow.’ And all the people shall say, ‘Amen.’

Exodus 12:49 There shall be one law for the native and for the stranger who sojourns among you.


I'm aware that this is a loaded question. I don't want to get into the politics of the consequences if the answer is "yes", except to note that answers of the form "The Bible can't mean that because it would be too inconvenient if it did" are bogus.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

your question is about to be closed. You might consider editing it to avoid making seem like you are asking an opinion regarding USA immigration policy. Objections might be withdrawn if you speak about the issue generation: does it apply to Christian nations as well as Israel?


In the USA there are some 40 million resident aliens
Are all these people "sojourners" in the Biblical meaning of the word?

The Bible doesn't use the word "sojourner"; it uses several different Hebrew words:

"תּוֹשָׁב" (H8453 tôšāḇ):

a dweller but not outlandish [H5237]; especially (as distinguished from a native citizen [active participle of H3427] and a temporary inmate [H1616] or mere lodger [H3885]) resident alien:—foreigner, inhabitant, sojourner, stranger.


"נָכְרִי" (H5237 nāḵrî):

strange, in a variety of degrees and applications (foreign, non-relative, adulterous, different, wonderful):—alien, foreigner, outlandish, strange(-r, woman).


"גָּרגֵּר" (H1616 gêr, gare):

properly, a guest; by implication, a foreigner: — alien, sojourner, stranger.


"לוּן" (H3885):

a primitive root; to stop (usually over night); by implication, to stay permanently; hence (in a bad sense) to be obstinate (especially in words, to complain):—abide (all night), continue, dwell, endure, grudge, be left, lie all night, (cause to) lodge (all night, in, -ing, this night), (make to) murmur, remain, tarry (all night, that night).



The verses cited in the question all use H1616.
So yes, in the modern world, non-citizens that are in the country would match the biblical use of this word, basically everyone else, whether illegal migrants, tourists, green-card holders, or whatever.

I don't want to get into the politics of the consequences if the answer is "yes"

It's not obvious what consequences you fear.
Just as in ancient Israel, the United States's constitution guarantees all rights (except with respect to voting) to everyone within the country, regardless of citizenship.
(If there were any doubt about it, that's the primary reason that many foreign prisoners were detained at Guantanamo Bay, because they would not be within the country.)

VTCs, isn't this question asking about "the meaning of that biblical text either in context or through a process of arriving at a particular interpretation"? Or is the problem that the text is only one word long?

I VTC because as the site meta (https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-can-this-site-distinguish-itself-from-christianity-se) makes clear: Any discussion of beliefs, doctrines or theology belongs on Christianity.SE.. The application of a text to a modern political issue is as clearly a discussion of belief and theology as is possible

+1 Also I won't join in the VTCs. The question can be salvaged by having it ask whether the OT standard applies to Christian and/or modern nations rather than the USA per se... and @RayButterworth 's answer will still work, with a minor edit or two.

@AviAvraham says "The application of a text to a modern political issue is as clearly a discussion of belief". It's worded awkwardly, but one could interpret the question as asking whether the American system is a good analogue for understanding the Israelite system. That is, the question is about the meaning of the Hebrew scripture.

Biblically speaking, the cultural context of a sojourner in these verses describes anyone who comes to live in Israel, adopting the customs, laws, culture and worship of God while abandoning those of their previous country. Ruth is the perfect example of a sojourner, and describes in brief the thinking around the concept - she has to abandon her gods and culture to become an Israelite, but still is regarded as a sojourner because of her bloodline.

"anyone who comes to live in Israel, adopting the customs, laws, culture and worship of God while abandoning those of their previous country" — Where do you get this definition from? That sounds like someone that has converted and become an Israelite, a naturalized citizen (as you say, like Ruth). The quoted verses use a word meaning "alien".

Even if you convert like Ruth, you cannot become an Israelite, that is why sojourner or 'resident forienger' is used in the OT text. It is a genetic, not a cultural or relgious distinction. In terms of the definition itself, the idea that you could move to ancient Israel and NOT convert was abhorrent and prohibited. Idolaters were not allowed to dwell within Israel and were put to death. So the only foriengers were people like Ruth who had completely abandoned their culture and religion (which were intertwined) to worship YAHWEH. even so, they were still seen as foriegn.

"Even if you convert like Ruth, you cannot become an Israelite … It is a genetic, not a cultural or religious distinction." — So her descendants would have been non-Israelite foreigners too, such as David and Jesus?

No, after one generation her children would be considered Israelites, since their father was an Israelite. Note that in the OT someone's identity and heritage was determined by their father, not their mother. That is also how Jesus is considered a son of David - through Joseph's genealogy and fatherhood. In their culture it didnt matter that he was adopted, he was considered 100% Joseph's.
Modern Judaism changes this way of tracking genealogy, and does so through the mother alone.
